# Loading file icons is sometimes very slow, for some files

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to load file icons on Windows effectively enough with Java, so that they can be displayed in a file explorer application.

Most of the time the icons load in about 2-15 milliseconds, but sometimes for some files loading a single icon can take up to 10 seconds (!). I simply use `FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(File)`. I also tried the JIconExtract-library (https://github.com/MrMarnic/JIconExtract), and it appears to have the same problem.

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Downloads");
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getSystemIcon(file);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(file.getName() + ": " + (end - start));
        }
    }
}
```

A sample output from a "slow run":

```
story.ni: 4
StructuredXmlEditor.exe: 96
stone_soup-0.21.1-win32-installer.exe: 798
stone_soup-0.21.1-console-win32.zip: 708
star.png: 2
StageUtils.java.zip: 2
SS2Tool-v.6.1.1.6.exe: 9268
Squiffy.5.1.1.Windows.exe: 10535
square.ttf: 1272
Spit_Splat-Mike_Koenig-1170500447.wav: 4
spelv104.exe: 31
spelv107.rar: 32
Speedy.zip: 2
```

Windows also seems to cache the icons or something, as subsequent runs are very fast -- for some time.

Why might loading an icon take up to 10 seconds? What kind of threading mechanism could I use to overcome this issue? I'm currently using simply an ExecutorService with few threads, but if loading a single icon can take up to 10 seconds then my threads are going to get stalled, and I see lots of files without icons for quite a some time. (I'm not very experienced with multithreading)

Comment: Have you tried looking at the size of the file you are trying to access?

Comment: Yes. For example, Squiffy.exe is almost 10 times larger than SS2Tool.exe, yet they take nearly the same time to load in the worst case.

Comment: Okay, have you tried working out where the icons are located for these programs/files? Maybe the implementation to find the icons struggles with short cuts or symbolic links. If this isn't the case either I can give you a hand with some of your mutli-threading code

Comment: Well, the examples I posted are from my Downloads folder, so the icons are mostly embedded into the executables. Continuing with the same examples: Squiffy.exe seems to have a "generic windows install icon", but SS2Tool.exe has a completely custom icon. Also, Square.ttf is a font, and it takes 1300 milliseconds to load its icon (in the worst case).